# How do you code an SQL query that determines if table A is a proper subset of table B?

Tags: sql, postgresql, set-theory

If A is a proper subset of B or vice versa, then the query should return true. if not, then false:

[image: If A or B is a proper set of each other, then true. if A or B is a improper set of each other, then false.]

This is the code to create table A and table B:

```
Create table A (i int);
Create table B (i int);

Insert into A values (1);
Insert into A values (2);
Insert into A values (3);

Insert into B values (2);
Insert into B values (3);
Insert into B values (6);
```

This is the code that i wrote:

```
SELECT Count(*) >= 1 
FROM A 
RIGHT JOIN B ON A=B 
WHERE A IS NULL;
```

I get a true, but it should be a false.

[image: 'True' output]

Does anybody know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Please explain what "A and B are proper set of each other" in words. Eeveryone does not master set theory.

Comment: Are you looking for the `intersect` operator? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4e10166af2cf8de4938a0bb88159de9f

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: I think OP wants false, but they get true (here, neither dataset is contained within the other).

Comment: But it would be good if @user14217364 could confirm!

Comment: @GMB Ah, OP is talking about proper **sub**sets, not proper sets. And I was afraid that I had forgotten my set theory... I'll go fix the question.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want the query to check if either A is proper subset of A, or if B is a proper subset of A (both cannot be true at the same time).

`A ⊂ B` reads as: every element of `A` can be found in `B`, and not all elements of `B` exist in `A`.

In SQL this would be a `full join` and conditional logic:

```
select 
       (bool_and(b.i is not null) and bool_or(a.i is null))    -- A ⊂ B
    or (bool_and(a.i is not null) and bool_or(b.i is null))    -- B ⊂ A
from a
full join b using (i)
```

Comment: Isn't that an `intersect`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I would think of this as two `except`s, where one must return something and not the other.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not Postgres specific.

```
select 1
from A full outer join B on B.i = A.i
having count(case when A.i is null then 1 end) = 0 or
       count(case when B.i is null then 1 end) = 0
```

You said "of each other" so I allowed for both options. Of course it you really mean to ask whether *A* is a proper subset of *B* then you really just want:

```
count(case when A.i is null then 1 end) = 0 and
count(case when B.i is null then 1 end) > 0
```

Counting nulls (on the *A* side) can also be expressed as:

```
count(*) - count(A.i)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of both those points. The question was poorly phrased when I answered it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the utility functions by [`intarray`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/intarray.html), this problem becomes much easier:

```sql
WITH A(i) AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1),
                 (2),
                 (3)) as a
), B(i) AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (2),
                 (3),
                 (6)) as b
)
-- The above is just fake data for A and B
SELECT (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(i) FROM A) <@ (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(i) FROM B)
```

where `<@` is the CONTAINED operator. It returns whether the left array is contained by the right array. If you want to account for either option, you could just chain the cases using `OR`:

```sql
WITH A(i) AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1),
                 (2),
                 (3)) as a
), B(i) AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (2),
                 (3),
                 (6)) as b
)
-- The above is just fake data for A and B
SELECT (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(i) FROM A) <@ (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(i) FROM B)
    OR (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(i) FROM A) @> (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(i) FROM B)
```